# Performance: Get Public IP address in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, performance

I am developing an MVC.ASP.Net application. I am trying to find the Public IP address of respective country.

```
Public static string GetIP()
{
     string IPAddress = null;


     IPAddress = WDA.CMS.Services.CacheService.getPublicIP;

     using (System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient())
     {
         // Take long time to respond.
         IPAddress = wc.DownloadString("http://icanhazip.com/"); 
     }

     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(IPAddress))
     {
         System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("(\\d{1,3}\\.){3}\\d{0,3}");
         if (IPAddress != null)
         {
             if (regex.IsMatch(IPAddress))
             {
                 IPAddress = regex.Match(IPAddress).Value.ToString();
             }
             else
             {
                 IPAddress = "";
             }
             regex = null;
        }

     }

     return IPAddress;
}
```

// In case of US: 209.105.127.206

This function is working correctly but I am trying to improve response time as this function is called many times. Could it be possible to modify this function to retrieve result faster. Any help/suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: This is going to sound a bit stupid but doesnt your public ip stay the same most of the time ? I would only try to download it once and cache it somewhere, if it changes, store it with a timestamp and try every n minutes/days whatever

Comment: If the service takes a long time to answer, there isn't much you can do about it

Comment: Cache previous results. Use an offline database. Increase your internet connection speed. Buy a faster CPU. Improve your RAM.

Comment: you'll probably find that the biggest slowdown in the code is the http request you're doing each time. there's VERY LITTLE you can do to change that, other than getting a faster network link, with fewer hops to your ip lookup service. even if you optimize the hell out of this code, you'll only save a few microseconds of processing time on your end, which will be vastly outweight by the milliseconds/seconds spent waiting for the network to bring back a response.

Comment: Exactly how many times per hour/minute/second do you expect your IP address to change?

Comment: @WorkofArtiz I am already caching an output of this method. Is it possible to improve response time of this method further?

Comment: @user3179537 I'm not seeing any caching. You should post that code because it's obviously broken.

Comment: i notice you call WDA...getip then immediately overwrite the result with the website, that seems wrong

Answer (score 1):

cache it. ie

```
static string myip;
static DateTime ipstamp;
...
if(myip == null||DateTime.Now-ipstamp> TimeSpan.FromHours(10))
{
   using (System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient())
     {
         // Take long time to respond.
         myip = wc.DownloadString("http://icanhazip.com/"); 
         ipstamp = DateTime.Now;
     }
}
```